# Google EdgeTPU can't get PWM to work with Python

Tags: python, linux, pwm, tpu, google-coral

Here is my testing code:

```
from periphery import PWM
import time

# Open PWM channel 0, pin 0
pwm = PWM(0,0)

# Set frequency to 1 kHz
pwm.frequency = 50
# Set duty cycle to 75%
pwm.duty_cycle = 0.02

pwm.enable()

print(pwm.period)
print(pwm.frequency)
print(pwm.enabled)

# Change duty cycle to 50%

pwm.duty_cycle = 0.05

pwm.close()
```

Problem is this part:

```
# Open PWM channel 0, pin 0
pwm = PWM(0,0)
```

I can see output when running `PWM(0,0)` `PWM(0,1)` `PWM(0,2)`

but I get the error messsage when trying to run the following:

`PWM(1,1)`

`PWM(2,2)`

```
mendel@elusive-jet:/sys/class/pwm$ sudo python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/testPWM.py
OSError: [Errno 19] No such device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/periphery/pwm.py", line 69, in _open
    f_export.write("%d\n" % pin)
OSError: [Errno 19] No such device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/testPWM.py", line 5, in <module>
    pwm = PWM(1,1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/periphery/pwm.py", line 44, in __init__
    self._open(channel, pin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/periphery/pwm.py", line 71, in _open
    raise PWMError(e.errno, "Exporting PWM pin: " + e.strerror)
periphery.pwm.PWMError: [Errno 19] Exporting PWM pin: No such device
```

Based off the document from both Coral and the library site:
https://coral.withgoogle.com/tutorials/devboard-gpio/

https://github.com/vsergeev/python-periphery

The

`PWM(1,1)`

`PWM(2,2)`

should have worked without issue, I can see the following directories existed:

```
"\sys\class\pwm\pwmchip0"
"\sys\class\pwm\pwmchip1"
"\sys\class\pwm\pwmchip2"
```

In the python-periphery source code 
https://github.com/vsergeev/python-periphery/blob/master/periphery/pwm.py

it should getting the path as following:

`PWM(1,1) ===> /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm1` if `pwm1` not exists, then it should call the `export` to generate it.

So, My main question are:

- What is `channel` and `pin` and how it is been used ?
- Why I'm not able to get PWM(1,1) PWM(2,2) to work ?

Thank you in advance.

**---------------2019.4.2 Update--------------------**

**I figured out the previous answer by myself (and thank you for anyone who provided help).**

**But as you can see from my own answer, I'm still not able to get the PWM to work as it is not output stable Voltage. (You can check out more detail below).**

I'm currently running into another issue in which the output voltage are not stable at all. So, here is what I did to test:

I set up both `Raspberry Pi 3+ Model B` and the `EdgeTPU Coral Board` with `50hz` PWM with `5%` duty cycle. Since both device have GPIO output 3.3V, My theory is, their output should be identical, but they are NOT.

Here are the voltage measured by using a Arduino UNO board: [Pi](https://github.com/CharlesCCC/edgetpuvision/blob/master/issue-files/pwm/Raspberry-Pi-50Hz-5-percent-duty-cycle.txt) vs. [EdgeTPU](https://github.com/CharlesCCC/edgetpuvision/blob/master/issue-files/pwm/Coral-Board-PWM-50hz-5-percent-duty-cycle.txt). (Note: all the voltage should be divide by 10). You can see there is a clear pattern(PWM) in the Pi output, alternating around 1.8v.  but if you look at the EdgeTPU output, you can see the voltage is all over the places and it is much lower voltage (1.1v vs 1.8v).

it clearly to me something wrong with the EdgeTPU PWM output, So I did further research. found out from the (limited) [document](https://coral.withgoogle.com/tutorials/devboard-gpio/), it says

> All GPIO pins have a **90k pull-down resistor** inside the iMX8M SOC that
>    is used by default during bootup, except for the I2C pins, which
>    instead have a pull-up to 3.3V on the SOM. However, **these can all be
>    changed with a device tree overlay that loads after bootup**.

Which lead me suspect the `90k pull-down resistor` might have lower the output voltage due to the fact of this formula `V=IR`. So, I'm thinking change the `device tree overlay` at bootup as it instructed. but, guess what, there is no documents on how to change it besides the following line from the `overlays.txt` file:

```
# List of device tree overlays to load. Format: overlay=<dtbo name, no extenstion> <dtbo2> ...
overlay=
```

I have searched all over the place, there is no document regarding to how does Mendel Linux device tree overlay should be configured. so, I'm currently stuck, If you know the answer, please share it, I would much appreciated.

I will share this question to the Coral Support team as well to see if they will get me any response.(FYI, I did send something to them back when I posted the original question, haven't hear anything from them yet, even tho their website says `We try to respond to inquiries within one business day — but often you'll get a response even quicker, usually a few hours.`) so, wish me luck. Will keep this answer updated if hear anything back.

Here is the passage/question I would like to convey to **Google/Google Cloud/Google EdgeTPU/Google Coral Board** teams also:

- Why choose python-periphery as the default library to implement GPIO 
  and PWM ?
- Why choose the Mendel Linux as the default OS, when there is no site/document or any sort to be found ?

Comment: It's difficult to determine anything about the waveform from the samples provided because the sampling rate is too low and the reading interval is not consistent. A 50Hz signal cycles every 20ms, which means you need to be taking samples every 10ms or more to get an accurate reading. These samples vary between 75-115ms, which is too slow to accurately measure the signal.

Comment: @Devunwired Okay, you said make sense to me. I will try to increase the sample rates to test it again. but just compare the results from Pi and the Coral board, you can tell there is clear different, right ? (with the same frequency and duty cycle)

Comment: You can't tell anything of value because it's not clear what point in the waveform you are gathering the sample (and ADCs carry residual voltage during the switch). You really need to validate this on an oscilloscope to see if the output timing is correct

Comment: As a side note, I just connect a scope to all of the three PWM outputs and their signal parameters are dead on with the Periphery code.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own an OScilloscope.  But I'm glad you are able to test it, I will try it again tonight. Thank you.

Comment: @Devunwired I tested it again today, it seems the PWM do works with a small LED light (I can confirm it working by dim the light). but I still can't get it to work with the SG90 Servo(http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/DE1_EE/stores/sg90_datasheet.pdf) I was able to control the servo easily with the Raspberry Pi.  I'm still suspecting the pull-down resistor might have draw the voltage too much. Would you please share how to set-up the device tree overlay on the Mendel Linux ? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191158/discussion-between-charlesc-and-devunwired).

Answer (score 2):

There appears to still be an outstanding question of 3.3V PWM operation (as opposed to 2.5, which is correctly noted as the voltage divider between the pin having a pull up enabled and every pin having a weak pull down).

The pin configuration for the device tree overlay can be found here: https://coral.googlesource.com/linux-imx/+/refs/heads/master/arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/fsl-imx8mq-phanbell.dts#171

The number there (0x7f), can be decoded with this bitmask: https://coral.googlesource.com/linux-imx/+/refs/heads/master/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/fsl%2Cimx8mq-pinctrl.txt.

2.5V comes from PUE (pull up enable) being set while all GPIOs have a weak pull down. If this is removed (and you should remove LVTTL and ODE for maximum drive strength), the IO will drive 3.3V. Here's an overlay that does it. To enable, copy pwm.dtbo to /boot and then edit overlays.txt to add pwm into the list (i.e. overlays=pwm)

[PWM Overlay](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/files/4955027/PWM_Overlay.zip)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation @Micheal Brooks! I have tried to implement an overlay for the google coral to change the gpio-mode to open drain. For this I have copied your example and modified the subnodes as well as the corresponding pins. You can find the .dts file [here](https://gist.github.com/Ecuashungo/10be022f5533a83e93601d9eef23a33f). The boot console says that the overlay loaded sucessfully, but checking the pins it did not work. Do you have any idea why that could be?

Answer (score 1):

> What is channel and pin and how it is been used ?

The **channel** maps to the driver chip in Linux sysfs (e.g. `pwmchip0`), and the **pin** maps to the individual outputs on each channel. Each channel will have `npwm` pins.

You can run the `pinout` command on your device to get some more details about the Peripheral ports on the 40-pin connector and the PWM channels they are connected to:

```
$ pinout
            3.3.V -> 1    2 <- 5V
 I2C2_SDA (i2c-1) -> 3    4 <- 5V
 I2C2_SCL (i2c-1) -> 5    6 <- GND
        UART3_TXD -> 7    8 <- UART1_TX
              GND -> 9   10 <- UART1_RX
        UART3_RXD -> 11  12 <- SAI1_TXC
 GPIO_P13 (gpio6) -> 13  14 <- GND
  PWM3 (pwmchip2) -> 15  16 <- GPIO_P16 (gpio73)
             3.3V -> 17  18 <- GPIO_P18 (gpio138)
        SPI1_MOSI -> 19  20 <- GND
        SPI1_MISO -> 21  22 <- GPIO_P22 (gpio140)
        SPI1_SCLK -> 23  24 <- SPI1_SS0
              GND -> 25  26 <- SPI1_SS1
 I2C3_SDA (i2c-2) -> 27  28 <- I2C3_SCL (i2c-2)
 GPIO_P29 (gpio7) -> 29  30 <- GND
 GPIO_P31 (gpio8) -> 31  32 <- PWM1 (pwmchip0)
  PWM2 (pwmchip1) -> 33  34 <- GND
        SAI1_TXFS -> 35  36 <- GPIO_P36 (gpio141)
GPIO_P37 (gpio77) -> 37  38 <- SAI1_RXD0
              GND -> 39  40 <- SAI1_TXD0
```

On this board, there is only one pin per channel (`cat npwm` returns 1) so the **pin number** in periphery would always be zero.

> Why I'm not able to get PWM(1,1) PWM(2,2) to work ?

Per the explanation above, here are the valid periphery commands to initialize each PWM on the dev board:

- PWM1 (Pin 32) --> `pwm = PWM(0,0)`
- PWM2 (Pin 33) --> `pwm = PWM(1,0)`
- PWM3 (Pin 15) --> `pwm = PWM(2,0)`

Comment: Thank you for the addition, but i actually already figured all of those out(you can also reference back to my own answer).I guess I should have update the question with the other issue, which I also illustrated on later part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, End up answering my own question again after couple days of research. Here is what I have found:

> What is channel and pin and how it is been used ?

**Answer:** `Channel` is like `lane` as if `PIN` is a high-way, some chip/pin support multiple `channel` some doesn't, you can figure this one out by using the following command(Using EdgeTPU for example, other Linux SOC should be similar): 
`cd /sys/class/pwm`  then do a `ls` should show multiple chip/pin like 
`pwmchip0  pwmchip1  pwmchip2`, let say you want to know how many `channel/lane` is `pwmchip0` support, then you `cd pwmchip0` and then `cat npwm` it should give you a number, for EdgeTPU it showing `1` which means 1 channel/lane supported for `pin PWM1`. You can do the same for `pwmchip1  pwmchip2 ... pwmchip#` 
(FYI, all the pin from EdgeTPU are support 1 channel only)

> Why I'm not able to get PWM(1,1) PWM(2,2) to work ?

This is the fun part, I have too much to say about this.

**Short Anwser:** `THEIR DOCUMENT IS WRONG.` `it should be PWM(Pin,Channel)`

**Long Anser**: In [here](https://github.com/vsergeev/python-periphery#pwm) it says you should initial the **PWM** as `PWM(Channel, Pin)` but by look at its implementation, it should be `PWM(Pin, Channel)` according to the [code](https://github.com/vsergeev/python-periphery/blob/master/periphery/pwm.py). and another great example of PWM standalone module [here](https://github.com/scottellis/pwmpy)(Highly suggest any EdgeTPU user go with this one instead of the `python-periphery`). 
I have [PR](https://github.com/vsergeev/python-periphery/pull/26) to update their document, but I want to say, their PWM definitely have not been tested by any means. Otherwise,the misleading info should have noticed by now. (TBH, the project seems dead, no update over a year, not even sure if my PR will get merged or not. Future Work: if my document correction PR get approved, I will work on get the stand alone PWM module PR to the python-periphery library)

> So,did everything working as it suppose to be after get PWM to work in
>   the code ?

**Answer:** Unfortunately **not** Please checkout my updated question.

Comment: Please avoid asking additional questions within an answer as there is not way to answer them. If the concerns here are tied to the original question, you can edit the question itself. Otherwise, consider asking a second question to address the new concern.