# Coral EdgeTPU PWM output low average voltage problem with Servo motor

Tags: python-3.x, pwm, servo, google-coral, adafruit-circuitpython

We have an MG996R model Servo motor.
The PWM output from the Coral is only 2.5V peak, and not very strong. We are using the HC4049 model buffer for this. But this doesn't work. We couldn't run our servo motor. Previously we have Raspberry PI 3 Model B and it was working smoothly.

We are following two libraries.
First, **Adafruit_CircuitPython_Motor**
And they have explained this situation in this article. https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-google-coral-linux-blinka/pwm-outputs-servos
We tried the codes in the "Servo Control" section

Second, **python-periphery**

```
from periphery import PWM
pwm = PWM(2, 0)
pwm.duty_cycle = 0
pwm.frequency = 5000
pwm.duty_cycle = 0.98
pwm.frequency = 5500
```

We didn't get errors in both libraries but nothing happened.
Some people have this problem but there is no solution.
[Google EdgeTPU can't get PWM to work with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385943/google-edgetpu-cant-get-pwm-to-work-with-python)

References.

```
Linux arid-goose 4.9.51-imx #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 31 01:58:26 UTC 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

```
mendel@jumbo-zebra:~$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Mendel GNU/Linux 4 (Day)"
NAME="Mendel GNU/Linux"
ID=mendel
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://coral.withgoogle.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://coral.withgoogle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://coral.withgoogle.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME="day"
```

Do you have an idea to increase the power of the PWM output?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You posted the same question [here](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/175#issuecomment-661129391). I'm reposting the answer here for other to reference!

A buffering circuit is required. The HC4049 is great for gluing logic chips together, but it is not intended for driving motors. The customer either has to design their own driver (hardware circuit) or they just drop in a driver chip like this one: https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/motor-drivers/brush-dc-motor-drivers/a3982

That isn't a recommendation for the exact chip since it'd depends on your usage.